# not equal condition in YII

Tags: php, yii, formatting, conditional-statements

I have a condition where I need to filter a dropdown list according to `employment_status = active` and `account_type != admin`

here is my code:

```
<?php
$employeesList = array();
$employees = Employee::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('employment_status' => 'active', 'account_type' ??? 'admin'));
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
   $employeesList[$employee->company_id] = $employee->getName();
} 
?>
```

how do i get the `'account_type' != 'admin'` ?

please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

```
$employees = Employee::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('employment_status' => 'active'), 'account_type' != 'admin');
```

Or,

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->condition = "account_type != 'admin' AND employment_status = :status";
$criteria->params = array (
    ':status' => "active",
);
$employees = Employee::model()->findAll( $criteria );
```

Answer (score 0):

In yii1,the below code worked for me.

```
$employees = Employee::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('employment_status' => 'active'), 'account_type <> "admin"');
```